# Using Svg to draw shapes then animate with easing/elasticity etc

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to suss out what the best way is to animate graphical elements on my website.

I've looked into html5 canvas, but it appears SVG is most appropriate.

I'll explain how things should work, and maybe you guys could give your opinions.

On the page, I want to have my products slide in and out when the user selects the arrows, with only one product in the center at a time. When the images slide in and out I want some sort of easing. Does SVG have different animation styles like elasticity etc...? Or should I just use jquery to animate?

Next, each product will have a description that will be contained in a shape. Maybe the shape will be randomly drawn, so I'll need a drawing api. I also want similar easing for this container as it will slide in.

I'm really confused about how svg integrates with the other web technologies.

edit:

Is it possible to animate the points of a svg polygon?

```
<svg id="svgelem2" height="190" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<polygon  points="0,0 800,0, 800,180 0,180 " fill="white" filter="url(#dropshadow)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Raphael.js library. It allows you to manipulate SVG at will.

http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: thanks I checked that out. I'm just wondering if I should be using SVG . Perhaps I can do all of this using javascript?

Comment: Yes, load of animations can be done by just manipulating dome, or even with css rules (on modern browsers). Check jquery effects, and css transistions.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with javascript, but on top of javascript you'll need to manipulate something in the DOM: either straight up HTML, or SVG, or something wrapped in one of the two.

There are several popular libraries that are either canvas based ([paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)) or SVG based ([d3](http://d3js.org/), [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)). My understanding is that if you want your final product to be available to as many platforms as possible (all the current versions of the top browsers, the last three versions of the top browsers, and the dominant mobile) - you need to stick with a library that is canvas based. Not all browsers support SVG equally well, or at all ([wikipedia has some good info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers) on this, of course :) ).

Animation is definitely possible if you render [SVG with paths](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/voronoi.html) (which you could do polygons, with paths)...I'm sure you could do it with an SVG polygon, but I couldn't find a ready example.

Personally, I *love* d3.js but I understand that it doesn't render/animate to canvas - however, paper.li and processing.js do render to the canvas or raphael to [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)...so if reaching the widest audience is a concern, you might wanna go that way.

This [table of browser support](http://caniuse.com/svg) for SVG may be helpful/informative in making your decision.

Comment: no, Raphael renders SVG not HTML5 canvas. But it does support older IE's because it can output VML as well

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this: http://svg-wow.org/photoAlbum/album.svg Put your mouse over the images at the bottom and they ease in and expand.